# Disable "Enjoy your app!" popup

Tags: google-play-store, notifications, google-account

Every now and then, after installing or updating an app from the Play Store, a popup with the following text appears:

> Enjoy your app! If you ever forget your password, we can help you restore access to your Google Play library and purchases. Tap "Continue" to tell us how to contact you.

I won't forget my password and I'm certainly not going to provide Google with information that might allow them to enable 2FA.

How do I disable this naggy popup?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK they will never enable 2FA without your explicit consent and it's easy to turn off again, so if that's all you're worried abb=out don't be.

Answer (score 2):

This message is because you do not have any [Account Recovery information](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3091378?hl=en) tied to your account. This is not some Malware, or anything harmful. They will not change any of your security settings by clicking it.

Clicking "continue" will ask you for additional information to verify your account and your device. You should enter the information, it is the information if you need to perform a password reset, or if you are unable to access your account via password and 2-step authentication, this will give google another way for you to verify you are you.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer my question. I know what the popup is about. I want to get rid of it without entering account recovery information.

Comment: Well, to be fair, you asked how to disable it. And the answer is to enter the recovery information. Google does not offer a way to disable this. It will stop asking once you give them the information. Entering this information will not enable 2-factor authentication. That is completely separate from this.

Comment: I would have said the same a few years ago. Then Yahoo permanently shut me out of my account when they suddenly enabled 2FA without my consent (and the recovery information wasn't up-to-date). Not a big deal as I wasn't using Yahoo for anything important, but it would be a minor disaster if it happened with Google.

Comment: Not having the recovery information is worse that having it out of date. And I am curious how yahoo enabled 2fa on you without your consent. Really though, you should use 2FA. Why would you want to rely on just a password that could be brute forced.

Comment: Apart from agreeing with you that this is a correct answer, @RyanConrad (+1 given) – I agree with the OP that this should be a decision left to the user. Give it a couple of "do you really want..." warning screens is OK, but forcing me to reveal details I don't want to give is blackmail. Not that "how to change the policy" is something for Android.SE – but I'd love to hear whether there's another way, and be it with "root powers". Same issue is bugging me, and like the OP, I don't want to give more details (but unlike him, no important things in my G-Account ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to this problem, but is only a temp fix. Go ahead and tap the button to continue and and it will take you to the recovery setup screen, then just tap the back button without inputting any information. Doing this will make Google Play think you've completed the recovery process, at least until it checks again, which seems to be every time they update the Google Play app[or 30 days, haven't quite figured out which].

I agree with you that it is a serious annoyance, but then again, if you've used the Play store on a phone or purchased anything then Google already has the information they're requesting and they simply want to encourage you to setup an account safeguard, which isn't unwise in some cases. They can NOT, however, force you to use anything you don't wish to as there are laws in many places that strictly prohibit them from forcing the public to use something they don't wish to. If they did, you'd have the full right to civil claim for damages, depending on where you live.

It's an annoyance for sure, but a minor one if you know how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way I have found to disable this popup is to remove Gapps upon installing a different rom for your android device. Or install a rom that has Gapps ommitted.  Of course this will "throw the baby out with the bath water", you will have to live without Google play services, and pretty much anything google.  Loss outweighs the gain in this case, so just make a VOIP number and give it that number instead of your cell or home.